# Display image in dropdown list in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm currently working on a project and my task is to build a feature for users to rate different countries in a dropdown list.

How to add a flag beside the name of the country in drop downlist?

Comment: That's not a Django question, that's an HTML (and JavaScript) question.

Comment: I used ModelForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to add the corresponding flag emojis to your country names.

If that doesn't fit your requirements, you will have to integrate a JavaScript  library, e.g. [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render).